# Is there a way that the user can leave the entry widgets blank without causing a problem later?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

i am having some trouble with the entry widget. I use the input to calculate some stuff but i want to be able to leave some entries blank without causing a problem. Right now i get error if i have some of them blank. This is because i use .get() to call instances from a dictionary so i can calculate with their attributes. Something like this :

```
  lipidia = float(kouti1p)*float(dic.get(kouti1f).lip) + float(kouti2p)*float(dic.get(kouti2f).lip) + float(kouti3p)*float(dic.get(kouti3f).lip)
```

i have tried making a nested loop that will check the entry price  and if its "" will insert 0 values to my calculations but it doesnt work:
      for n in numbers:

```
   if dic_kouthkia.get(n) == "" :

        dic_kouthkiaf.get(dic_kouthkia.get(n)).insert(0,vrwmi)
        dic_kouthkiaf.get(dic_kouthkia.get(n)).focus_set()

        dic_kouthkiaa.get(dic_kouthkiap.get(n)).insert(0,0)
        dic_kouthkiaa.get(dic_kouthkiap.get(n)).focus_set()
```

when i go and add values to all entry spaces everything work fine.. even if i use 0 to 'hide' them from the result. when i leave them blank i get problem.

Comment: "i get problem" is not enough information. Please [edit] your question and be very specific. Add a full traceback if possible.

Answer (score 1):

use zero as a default value for `get()`

example:

```
mydict.get('someKey', 0) # if key is not existed return zero
```

further explanation:

`dict.get(key, default)` If the key exists in the dict, then the value for that key is returned. If it does not exist, then the default value specified as the second argument to `get()` is returned.

in case if a second argument is not provided like `dict.get(key)` the default value is `None`

references: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/not_using_get_to_return_a_default_value_from_a_dictionary.html#not-using-get-to-return-a-default-value-from-a-dict)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it was really helpful .